# Parse csv text with an accent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, encoding

I am reading of a CSV file and I can't seem to properly store a word with an accent on it.

```
csv_raw = File.read(self.attachment.path)
csv_text = csv_raw.encode("utf-8", :invalid => :replace)
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => "iso-8859-1:utf-8")
csv.each do |row|
  row
```

A value of row of the csv file I want to parse is `Lerías`. However, it is getting through as `Ler�as`

Comment: What format is the input file? You probably need to do `File.open(self.attachment.path, encoding: 'ISO-8859-1').read` instead.